# Create a PHP application vulnerable to multi-statement SQL injections

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, sql-injection

I am trying to create an application in PHP using PDO that is deliberately vulnerable to SQL injection for educational purposes. The underlying database is Postgres.

With `pdo->query` I can demonstrate `' OR 1=1; --` style injections easily enough with something like:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT amount FROM client.transactions WHERE clientid='". $id ."' ORDER BY amount DESC");
```

But if I try to piggyback a second statement with something like `'; UPDATE client.transactions SET amount=50000000 WHERE id=1; --` it does not work as the statement is sent as a prepared statement after `$id` is appended, and Postgres gives:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

Ideally the code would be fairly natural as I would like to share and compare with a version using `pdo->prepare`. What I guess I would need is something like `mysqli::multi_query` but that I could run on Postgres, or any way to execute an SQL query/statement that is not prepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [`pg_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) rather than PDOs.

```
$conn = pg_connect("host = ... port = ... dbname = ... user = ... password = ...");
$stmt = pg_query($conn, "SELECT amount FROM client.transactions WHERE clientid='". $id ."' ORDER BY amount DESC");
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   // ...
}
```

This is vulnerable to `'; UPDATE client.transactions SET amount=50000000 WHERE id=1; --` style attacks.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't meet the "I am trying to create an application in PHP using PDO" requirement of the question.

Comment: @Nick, that is true, hence I have not accepted the answer. But this is a reasonable alternative. If there is an answer using PDO that looks natural, I will rather accept that one (though I have not found a solution and doubt that one exists, other than artificially parsing the statements by `;`).